# Distance tracking and updating google maps in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, mobile, geolocation

so i'm currently working on an exercise application for a mobile device that tracks the location of the user while constantly updating the distance they have traveled. I can get the starting location of the user easy enough but its actually tracking them that I have no idea how to even start.  I have a button for the user to get the current location called 'location' and i have a button called 'record' that will actually start the tracking process.

I know it has something to do with watchPosition() but im not quite sure how to use it and how to make it work with what i currently have.  This is the first time ive done anything that required geoLocation.

Any helped would be much apreciated.

```
<script>
            var c = function(position){
                var     latitude = position.coords.latitude,
                        longitude = position.coords.longitude,
                        acc = accuracy.coords.accuracy,
                        coords = position+ ', ' + long;
                        timeStamp = position.timestamp;

                document.getElementById('google_map').setAttribute('src', 'https://maps.google.co.uk/?q=' + coords + '&z=50&output=embed');
            }

            var e = function(error){
                switch(error.code){
                    case 0:
                        updateStatus("There was an error while retrieving your location: " +
                                error.message);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        alert("The user prevented this page from retrieving a location.");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        updateStatus("The browser was unable to determine your location: " +
                                error.message);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        updateStatus("The browser timed out before retrieving the location.");
                        break;
                }
            }

            document.getElementById('location').onclick = function() {
               var watchId = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(c, e, {
                    enableHighAccuracy: true,
                    timeout: 10000,
                    maximumAge: 1000
                });
                return false;
            }

            document.getElementById("stop").onclick = function(){
                navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);
            }

        </script>
```